# Deployment of Qt apps under Linux

Tags: qt, ubuntu, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my qt app under Ubuntu.
I have Qt5.1.1. Libraries are linked dynamically.

In main()

```
QStringList paths = QCoreApplication::libraryPaths();
paths.append("libs");
paths.append("platform");
paths.append("audio");
paths.append("designer");
paths.append("sqldrivers");
QCoreApplication::setLibraryPaths(paths);
```

Folder structure (ls -Rl):

```
total 3184
drwxr-xr-x 2 viktor viktor    4096 Oct 25 10:09 audio
drwxr-xr-x 2 viktor viktor    4096 Oct 25 10:09 designer
drwxr-xr-x 2 viktor viktor    4096 Dec  5 12:18 libs
drwxr-xr-x 2 viktor viktor    4096 Oct 25 10:09 platforms
drwxr-xr-x 2 viktor viktor    4096 Dec  5 12:18 sqldrivers
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor 3237902 Dec  5 13:06 App

./audio:
total 84
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor 84564 Aug 27 14:24 libqtmedia_pulse.so

./designer:
total 32
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor 14820 Aug 27 14:24 libqdeclarativeview.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor 15248 Aug 27 14:24 libqwebview.so

./libs:
total 86524
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor 22315900 Apr 29  2013 libicudata.so.51
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor  2698565 Apr 29  2013 libicui18n.so.51
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor  1742896 Apr 29  2013 libicuuc.so.51
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor  4721396 Oct 25 10:10 libQt5Core.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor  4629056 Aug 27 14:23 libQt5Gui.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor   874308 Aug 27 14:23 libQt5Multimedia.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor  1406652 Aug 27 14:23 libQt5Network.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor   397104 Aug 27 14:23 libQt5OpenGL.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor   334468 Aug 27 14:23 libQt5PrintSupport.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor  2705336 Aug 27 14:23 libQt5Qml.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor  3285156 Aug 27 14:23 libQt5Quick.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor   224744 Aug 27 14:21 libQt5Sensors.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor   256756 Aug 27 14:23 libQt5Sql.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor  4627352 Aug 27 14:23 libQt5V8.so.5.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor 31642416 Aug 27 14:23 libQt5WebKit.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor   241052 Aug 27 14:23 libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor  6465512 Aug 27 14:23 libQt5Widgets.so.5

./platforms:
total 1500
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor  167272 Aug 27 14:24 libqlinuxfb.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor   30600 Aug 27 14:24 libqminimal.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor  134012 Aug 27 14:24 libqoffscreen.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor 1196984 Aug 27 14:24 libqxcb.so

./sqldrivers:
total 732
-rwxr-xr-x 1 viktor viktor 747196 Aug 27 14:24 libqsqlite.so
```

But when I try to run app I got:

> error while loading shared libraries: libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I recommend you read something about packages in Debian. In this package you should define package dependencies (so Debian will instal with your package other required libraries). Considered using different build manager, see this page https://quickmediasolutions.com/blog/15/creating-debian-packaging-for-a-qt5-application

Comment: Oh, I know about packages. Nevertheless, qt app need a few files to be present with it(like libQt5*.so). Thanks for you link)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but probably you should append not only the directory names, but also the full path. Get the application directory, and append to it the sub-directory names.

```
QString appFilePath = QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath();

QStringList paths = QCoreApplication::libraryPaths();
paths.append(QString("%1/%2").arg(appFilePath).arg("libs"));
paths.append(QString("%1/%2").arg(appFilePath).arg("platform"));
...
```

Comment: To use QCoreApplication function applicationFilePath() I need to create an instance of QApplication, else it returns an empty string. But If I try to create QApplication object it throw and error I've posted.